# Moving on in candy crush level 35 in a laptop

Tags: candy-crush-saga

How can I get past level 35 without paying on a laptop please?  I have read the way of doing it on a tablet or phone, but I play via Facebook on my laptop.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't matter where you play. If you are playing with Facebook and you reach a block level, you need three of your Facebook friends help.

Ask people sending them requests to unlock your way to the next section in order to cotinue playing.

[image: Unlock stage example]

Comment: Yeah, pay, ask friends or wait till you get the option to unlock the level by playing. Not sure when this option rises but i had it several times. However you need to clear 3 levels and between these levels you have a cooldown time of 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to ask 3 friends to help you. 3 friends shouldn't be too much and the fact that Candy Crush is quite a bit popular.

Also, I heard that there is this thing called "Mystery Quests" where you do a quest every 24 hours. You'll need to do this like 3 times in total if you don't want to ask. However, this only works on iOS version I believe.

http://candy-crush-saga.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_Quests